# "Shadowbox is not defined" but there is here?

Tags: javascript, html, shadowbox

In our project,when I try to call Shadowbox.init in html,it didn't work.

```
$(window).load(function() {
Shadowbox.init({
    skipSetup: true
});
```

I declared :

```
{js src="linkzutils.js,shadowbox/shadowbox.js"}
```

There is a correct folder and path, but firebug returns;

> **Shadowbox is not defined**

Note:Our server folder/file permissions are true.

Why it can't work ?

Comment: When you view the 'scripts' tab, are you able to find shadowbox.js in the list?

Comment: Oh, the shadowbox.js is not found in the scripts tab.

Comment: Aha! Since the shadowbox.js file is not being shown in the scripts tab, you have a few ways to check what's up. First, see where firebug is requesting the script from. You should have a 404 error somewhere.

Comment: I noticed that inside your 'src' you have a comma, I'm not sure what you're using to load this script, but that doesn't look like a valid path.

Comment: Ok, it's interesting but when I try http://.../shadowbox/shadowbox.js, it didn^t return 404, it works...?

Comment: Ok, I changed it like {js src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"}, but not work.

Comment: what other errors you have? and what you mean, that {js src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"} doesn't work? it loads or not? just give us screenshot of scripts tab, because i can hardly decrypt what you mean

Comment: Are you trying to include this script from an HTML file?

Comment: So sorry the problem is about apache, defining wrong document root.Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a newer version of WordPress you might see this issue. It's most likely because it has not been updated. Read here on why and grab a current copy of the plugin.

http://sivel.net/2011/12/shadowbox-js-plugin-pulled-from-the-wordpress-org-repository/